# Error creating a bean with a particular name

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm getting an error, "Error creating bean with name 'roleJpaRepository'... No property role found for type RoleEntity!"  I have a Java Spring Boot application running Spring Boot version 2.2.6.RELEASE. Here is the pertinent information:

Error Message:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleJpaRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.microservices.entity.RoleEntity com.microservices.repo.RoleJpaRepository.findByRole_name(java.lang.String)! No property role found for type RoleEntity!
```

RoleEntity

```
import lombok.*;
import org.hibernate.Hibernate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import javax.persistence.*;
@Repository
@Entity(name="role")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RoleEntity {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "role_sequence",
            sequenceName = "role_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "role_sequence"
    )

    @Column(
            name = "id",
            updatable = false,
            unique = true,
            nullable = false
    )
    private int id;
    @Column(
            name = "role_name",
            unique = true,
            nullable = false,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    )
    private String role_name;


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o != null) {
            Hibernate.getClass(this);
            Hibernate.getClass(o);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }
}
```

RoleJpaRepository

```
import com.microservices.entity.RoleEntity;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;


public interface RoleJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<RoleEntity, Integer> {

    RoleEntity findByRole_name(String role_name);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't following [standard Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) for your variables, so the automated query generation stuff in Spring Data JPA isn't able to understand what you mean by `findByRole_name`. It can't parse that and figure out that you are referring to a property named `role_name`.

You need to rename the `role_name` property to `roleName` to match the standard naming convention. Then your repository method would be `findByRoleName` and Spring Data JPA will be able to interpret that.

Comment: Adding to this, [the underscore in JPA queries has a purpose](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Mark!  I need to pay more attention to naming conventions.  You're a time-saver!